# Can international students get paid from other countries while in US on F-1 visa?

Tags: usa

I knew students with F-1 Visa cannot get any paid outside their school, I just feel curious is that legal if they get paid from their mother country while in the U.S.

Now I knew that is also incorrect! You can get paid when you are in your mother country, but once you in the U.S. using the F-1 Visa you cannot do that!

So this question can be closed now! Thanks for your help!

Comment: See https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/students-and-exchange-visitors/students-and-employment for information about the type of work allowed on an F-1 visa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be working and you will be physically in the USA. For immigration purposes, you are working in the USA in a student visa, without proper authorization.

Therefore, no you may not work, even if you're getting paid abroad, while in the USA. Being a F-1 visa holder allows you to work in certain conditions. However, none of them allows you to work for costumers abroad like you want.

While some may argue that the USCIS may never find out that you're working, you risk jeopardizing future immigration status (such as a Work or Family Green Card) by violating your student visa. Immigrant visa applicants face way more scrutiny than student visa applicants and you will likely have to disclose your violation.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I will obey the laws, forever!